# Impossible to change Translate and Rotate in Transform's panel but Scale yes for one object?

Tags: transforms, 3d-manipulator

I created a scene where I have many objects. After many hours of work I note that it is impossible to change the translation and the rotation of one object from the Transform's panel but I can change the scale. I can translate and rotate my object only by the manipulator.

I try to copy this object to another file , so I can use Transform's panel as usual.

You can test my problem with 2 files :

- https://share.orange.fr/#4zeSip4WlX254dbe658f
  it is the original file (where is the problem) after I deleted the other objects.
- https://share.orange.fr/#4UdPsO4rJX254dbe6529
  it is a copy of my object.

On the other hand, I don't understand why the first file is about 35 Mo and the second only 3 Mo.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The first file is too big to upload in https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I baked the first file. Perhaps this action explains the size of the file.